# How to validate date using DatePipe in Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, date, date-pipe

I have bsDatepicker with bsConfig and I'm trying to validate it, to make sure it is with the right format. The problem is that bsDatepicker create a date in a different format so I can't validate it.

The date string is:

```
Mon Apr 01 2019 19:05:36 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I'm trying to transform it using DatePipe like:

```
dateStr = this.datepipe.transform(date.toDateString(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

What I'm getting is null. The expected result will be 04/01/2019.
Any idea why the datepipe failed to transform?
Thanks.

Comment: did you solve your issue? is there any answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static datePipeEn: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
```

Solved my problem, I hope it will help someone with similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

date.toDateString you are missing parentheses date.toDateString()

Comment: I added parentheses, still with no change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `toDateString()` to that time. You can parse to Date like this

```
this.dateStr = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(date.toDateString()) ,'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepipe-in-component-test

Answer (score 0):

The date can be converted in typescript to this format 'yyyy-MM-dd' by using Datepipe

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'

constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe){}

myFunction(){
 this.date=new Date();
 let latest_date =this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'mm-dd-yyyy');
}
```

and just add Datepipe in 'providers' array of app.module.ts. Like this:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'

providers: [DatePipe]
```

Comment: dateStr = this.dp.transform(new Date(date), 'MM-dd-yyyy') throw exception

Comment: what kind of exception